# Sharepoint 2010 databases are in restoring state

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, database, content-database

I have a single server in my SharePoint 2010 server farm. Today some of users complained about that some of Infopath forms can not be opened. When I checked the SOL Server Management Studio I saw that some of my databases are in *Restoring* state as you see in the image below!!!
[image]

Do you know any reason why this has happened and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: did somebody try to restore the database? if you have DBA or other user having access to SQL server check it, and also check SQL log files, when restore started and which account.

Comment: and if it real recovery and taking long time, check this http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/07/19/sql-server-database-in-restoring-state-for-long-time/

Comment: The admin says he has not restored databases!

Comment: what sql logs telling?

Comment: Can you confirm if mirroring is enabled for these databases ?

Comment: @Arko D: There is no mirroring or HA feature enabled.